# Can a generic interface inherit from an interface with generic methods (or vice versa) for injection?

Tags: c#

Given the following interfaces:

```
public interface IMessageDeserializer
{
    T Deserialize<T>(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> memory);
}

public interface ITypedMessageDeserializer<out T>
{
    T Deserialize(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> memory);
}

public interface IMessageSerializer
{
    ReadOnlyMemory<byte> Serialize<T>(T obj);
}

public interface ITypedMessageSerializer<in T>
{
    ReadOnlyMemory<byte> Serialize(T obj);
}
```

And the following implementations:

```
public class JsonMessageSerializer : IMessageSerializer, IMessageDeserializer
{
    public ReadOnlyMemory<byte> Serialize<TMessage>(TMessage obj)
    {
        return JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(obj, typeof(TMessage));
    }

    public TMessage Deserialize<TMessage>(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> memory)
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TMessage>(memory.Span)!;
    }
}

public class ProtoMessageSerializer : ITypedMessageSerializer<IMessage>, ITypedMessageDeserializer<ProtoResponse>
{
    public ReadOnlyMemory<byte> Serialize(IMessage message)
    {
        return message.ToByteArray();
    }

    public ProtoResponse Deserialize(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> memory)
    {
        return ProtoResponse.Parser.ParseFrom(new ReadOnlySequence<byte>(memory));
    }
}
```

Is there a way to have IMessageDeserializer inherit from ITypedMessageDeserializer (or vice versa) so that both concrete deserializers can be injected through their common interface into a message subscriber class like the one below?

```
public class MessageSubscriber<TMessage, TMessageDeserializer>
    where TMessageDeserializer : IMessageDeserializer<TMessage>
{
    public MessageSubscriber(TMessageDeserializer md)
    {
        ...
    }

    public Task HandleMessage(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> memory)
    {
        ...
        var message = _md.Deserialize(memory);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: _"so that both concrete serializers can be injected through a common interface into other code"_ - can you please explain the use case?

Comment: As written, there doesn't seem to be a common interface you could create.  If, however, you constrained `T` in all 4 interfaces with `where T : IMessage`, then perhaps you could build a truly common interface (or have the typed interfaces implement the non-typed ones).  Can you constrain `T` in this way, or do you not have the ability to refactor/redefine the interfaces?

Comment: @GuruStron I updated the post above, hopefully the update makes it more clear.

Comment: @SeanSkelly I have full control over all of the code (interfaces, serializers, subscribers). The interfaces + subscriber implementation would be in a library and the consuming code would provide an implementation of the serializer/deserializer.

Comment: @yenta tbh it does not.

Comment: @GuruStron which part is unclear?

Comment: @yenta how do you imagine the DI setup here? What is the usage? Do you use build in DI?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to try to combine those to interfaces but just use wrappers (i.e. composition over inheritance). For example if you are using build into the framework DI you can leverage the ability to register open generics:

Classes:

```cs
internal class MyClass {}
internal class MyClass2{}

internal class MyDeSer : ITypedMessageDeserializer<MyClass>
{
    public MyClass Deserialize(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> memory) => new();
}

public interface IMessageDeserializer
{
    T Deserialize<T>(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> memory);
}

public interface ITypedMessageDeserializer<out T>
{
    T Deserialize(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> memory);
}

class MessageDeserializer : IMessageDeserializer
{
    public T Deserialize<T>(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> memory) => default!; // some actual impl here
}

internal class SerWrapper<T> : ITypedMessageDeserializer<T>
{
    private readonly IMessageDeserializer _genSer;

    public SerWrapper(IMessageDeserializer genSer)
    {
        _genSer = genSer;
    }

    public T Deserialize(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> memory) => _genSer.Deserialize<T>(memory);
}
```

And registration and usage:

```cs
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton<IMessageDeserializer, MessageDeserializer>();
// register "default" typed serializer as wrapper
services.AddSingleton(typeof(ITypedMessageDeserializer<>), typeof(SerWrapper<>));
// "override" for custom one
services.AddSingleton<ITypedMessageDeserializer<MyClass>, MyDeSer>();

var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

// Uses custom one:
Console.WriteLine(sp.GetRequiredService<ITypedMessageDeserializer<MyClass>>() is MyDeSer); // True
// Uses "default" one
Console.WriteLine(sp.GetRequiredService<ITypedMessageDeserializer<MyClass2>>() is SerWrapper<MyClass2>); // True
```